# How to end conversation due to my own limitations in Korean

Tags: korean

I am learning Korean and I have just about enough knowledge to say greetings and order my food in a restaurant (spoken and written). But sometimes my server will assume I know more and I won't be able to understand what they say to me. When I was learning Spanish I would say "Lo siento, no entiendo, solo estoy aprendiendo" meaning "Sorry, I don't understand, I am just learning". Can someone give me some similar polite phrases I could use when this happens in Korean?

Also, to be polite, before speaking Spanish to someone in a restaurant I would usually say something like "Puedo practicar mi español por favor?" meaning "Can I practice my Spanish please?" to make sure they want to be talked to in Spanish and to let them know I am learning (they usually appreciate this and speak to me a little slower). Should I do this in Korean? I have less intuition about the culture, politeness, and formality as I do with Mexican and South American.

For context I am located in Seattle, WA.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to say 죄송해요, 한국어 조금만 알아요 or 한국어를 조금만 할 수 있어요. It means, Sorry, I know only a little bit of korean / I can speak only a little korean.